# Getting error while adding multiple NSG rules

Tags: azure, powershell

I am working on PowerShell script which needs to add multiple inbound and outbound NSG rules which is present in the excel sheet. Multiple port ranges are defined in the NSG rules excel sheet for each rule. when I execute the code getting below error:

> Security rule has invalid Port range. Value provided:
> `42`,`53`,`88`,`123`,`135`,`49152-65535`,`389`,`445`,`5722`. Value
> should be an integer OR integer range with '-' delimiter. Valid range
> 0-65535.
> | StatusCode: 400 ReasonPhrase: Bad Request ErrorCode: SecurityRuleInvalidPortRange ErrorMessage: Security rule has invalid
> Port range. Value provided:
> | `42`,`53`,`88`,`123`,`135`,`49152-65535`,`389`,`445`,`5722`. Value should be an integer OR integer range with '-' delimiter. Valid
> range 0-65535.

I have tried by changing the port range format like "42", "53" etc and '42','53' but not working. can some one please help me to fix this error.

code:

```
# Sign in to your Azure account
Connect-AzAccount
Install-Module -Name ImportExcel -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser

$subscription = Read-Host "Enter the Subscription Name or ID"
Set-AzContext -Subscription $subscription

$resourcegroups = $args[0]

$nsgName = "TestNSG"

$nsgObj = Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup -Name $NSG

$rules = Import-Excel -Path ./home/lokesh/NSG_Rules.xlsx

foreach ($rule in $rules) {
  $Params = @{
    'Name'                     = $rule.Name
    'Protocol'                 = $rule.Protocol
    'Direction'                = $rule.Direction
    'Priority'                 = $rule.Priority
    'SourceAddressPrefix'      = $rule.SourceAddressPrefix
    'SourcePortRange'          = $rule.SourcePortRange
    'DestinationAddressPrefix' = $rule.DestinationAddressPrefix
    'DestinationPortRange'     = $rule.DestinationPortRange
    'Access'                   = $rule.Access
    'Description'              = $rule.Description
  }
  $nsgObj | Add-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig @Params | Set-AzNetworkSecurityGroup
}
```

Comment: I’m guessing your excel file has a column called ```DestinationPortRange``` which has literal strings like ```42,53,88,123,135,49152-65535,389,445,5722``` in it - this is a *single* string that contains a comma separated list. What you need to provide to ```Add-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig``` is an *array* of individual values - e.g. ```@(42, 53, 88, 123, 135, “49152-65535”, 389, 445, 5722)```, so you’ll need to convert the string into the appropriate array yourself before you call ```Add-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig```…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Preface**:

- The following applies to any scenario, notably including CSV data parsed with [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv), in which what is conceptually an *array* of values is *represented as* a *single string* in which tokens are listed with separators, e.g. `'1, 2, 3'`, and where such an "array string" must be converted to an *actual* array.

---

[mclayton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3156906/mclayton) has provided the crucial pointers:

- You're using the values of *single cells* from an Excel worksheet as your port arguments, which are reflected in the `.SourcePortRange` and `.DestinationPortRange` *properties* of the objects that the third-party [`Import-Excel`](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel) cmdlet parsed the worksheet into.
- Since a single cell cannot contain an *array* of values, a value such as `42,53,88,123,135,49152-65535,389,445,5722` is a *single string* that happens to *represent* an array (list) of values.
- The `-SourcePortRange` and `-DestinationPortRange` *parameters* of the [`Add-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/add-aznetworksecurityruleconfig) cmdlet require are `[string[]]`-typed, i.e they require an *array* of string values, *each of which* either represents a *single* port number (e.g. `42`) or a *single range* of port numbers (e.g. `49152-65535`).
- Therefore, you **must manually convert each string *representing* an array into an *actual* array** and pass the latter to the cmdlet.

In the context of your code:

```bash
# ...
  $Params = @{
    # ...
    'SourcePortRange'        = $rule.SourcePortRange      -replace ' ' -split ','
    # ...
    'DestinationPortRange'   = $rule.DestinationPortRange -replace ' ' -split ','
    # ...
  }
```

- [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) `' '` removes any spaces from the string (to allow for input strings such as `'42, 53, 49152 - 65535'`)
- [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) `','` splits the resulting string into an array of (string) tokens by `,`

---

A **simple example**:

The following converts an "array string" into an actual array and prints each element of the resulting array enclosed in `[...]`:

```bash
'42, 53, 49152 - 65535' -replace ' ' -split ',' |
  ForEach-Object { "[$_]" }
```

Output:

```bash
[42]
[53]
[49152-65535]
```

Note:

- Given that the input is a string and that only *string* operators are used, the resulting array's elements are invariably strings (of type `[string]`) too.
- If your "array string" contains only representations of single numbers and you want your array to contain actual *numbers*, you can *cast* to the desired numeric type, say, `[int]`, in which case you don't even need to remove incidental whitespace (i.e., the `-replace ' '` part isn't needed); e.g.:

  ```bash
  # Returns an array of [int] values (System.Int32)
  [int[]] ('1, 2, 3' -split ',')
  ```